# Result of monad inside monad transformer

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

This is my first acquaintance with Monad Transformers, so the answer might be obvious.

Let's say I am inside a do block of type StateT MyMonad MyType, I want to make another function of the same type both modify the state and return a value of type MyMonad MyType. How can I achieve that? I think the examples [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Simple_StateT_use) show it in guessSession, yet I can't seem to understand how to apply it!

Comment: In case you don't know about hoogle: http://www.haskell.org/hoogle

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to use the underlying monad in a monad transformer, you can use `lift`:

```
lift :: (MonadTrans t, Monad m) => m a -> t m a
```

In this case, `t` is `StateT MyState`, and `m` is `MyMonad`. So, for example:

```
foo :: StateT MyState MyMonad MyType
foo = do
  modify $ \s -> s+1
  lift $ doSomethingInMyMonad 42
```

Monad transformers aren't "layered on" in the sense that you'd return a value of type `MyMonad MyType` from inside; it's a more literal *transformation:* they turn a monad into a new one that has the ability to run actions in the transformed monad. So, you can think of `StateT s m` as just the regular `State s` monad, except that you can also use `lift` to run turn actions in `m` into actions in `StateT s m`.

If you're using the standard [Monad Transformer Library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl) (mtl) transformers like `StateT`, `ReaderT`, etc., you don't actually have to use `lift`; things like `modify` and `ask` work in *any* monad with the right transformer somewhere in the stack. (A stack is just a tower of transformed monads, like `StateT s (ReaderT r IO)`.)

Additionally, if you have a large stack with `IO` at the bottom, there's a convenience function for lifting an `IO` action up any number of layers:

```
liftIO :: (MonadIO m) => IO a -> m a
```

So `liftIO (putStrLn "Hello, world!")` works in `IO`, `StateT Int IO`, `ContT r (WriterT [String] IO)`, and so on.

(As an additional note, `foo` here isn't actually a function; a more accurate term is *action* or *computation*.)

Comment: I think I understand. Just to be perfectly clear. Imagine that I did a <- doSomethingInMyMonad 42 before adding StateT. Now I do a <- lift $ doSomethingInMyMonad 42. Correct?

Comment: @aelguindy: Yep! If you have a section of code that just uses `MyMonad`, you can also lift a whole do block: `lift $ do ...`.

Comment: Thanks! Not sure if this is the correct place to ask, but is there an equivalent to lift but with 2 arguments, lift2? *Stupid question!* Found out the answer

Comment: @aelguindy: What would it do? If you want to use a function like `f :: T1 -> T2 -> MyMonad T3`, you can just do `lift (f a b)` (equivalently: `lift $ f a b`). `lift` doesn't lift functions at all, just monadic computations.

Comment: Was just about to say that I thought of! Thanks again :-). I think I completely understand now!